# How to cover concrete foundation curbs in finished basement. Time and money deficient!

Tags: drywall, concrete

I have 11" high x 2" deep foundation curbs running through my downstairs bedrooms. I have a slab foundation, so the curbs are above grade. I've never had issues with moisture (in 10 years), but...it does rain here.
The permit inspector said I could just glue purple (moisture resistant) drywall to the curb. My contractor says, "hell no". I want to believe the inspector because it would be easier and cheaper. (Cheaper because my drywall guys will include that in the price we've already agreed on, so...no extra output)

I know the furring strips would be a better way to go about this, but it's more of a pain, and I'm not sure about the rules for screwing things into a foundation wall. I'm worried that might compromise the wall. Also, it would definitely cost more in labor.

My contractor tells me to use vinyl plank flooring on the curb, and then just paint over them.

The drywall folks are taping and mudding tomorrow (I only just found out this was an issue).

I'm trying to figure out if there's something I can do to make this look better today.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A few pictures would sure help.